# What is the SQL Command for inserting into a table that has no non-identity columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has a single identity column. What is the SQL command for inserting a row into table that only has a single identity column where I want to use the identity column's auto-generation?

I've tried

```
INSERT INTO TableName
INSERT INTO TableName () VALUES ()
INSERT INTO TableName (Id) VALUES (DEFAULT)
```

None worked in SQL Server 2008 R2. Id is an identity column.

Comment: Either of the keywords `DEFAULT` or `NULL` can be used as the value in an INSERT statement - these trigger the database to use the default constraint, if one exists for the column.

Comment: Exception they don't work in this case because you can't insert them into the identity column.

Comment: Thankfully IDENTITY is deprecated for ANSI Sequences in SQL Server 2012 so things can get back to normal :p

Comment: What is replacing identity columns in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Sequences are replacing IDENTITY

Comment: @OMGPonies I didn't see anything about IDENTITY being deprecated, though I did look through the list of deprecated features in Denali. Sequences, I think, are the better route, but I imagine IDENTITY columns are going to be around for awhile.

Comment: I too would like to know where there is mention of IDENTITY being deprecated. Any information on when to use IDENTITY instead of sequences would also be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TableName DEFAULT VALUES;
```

> [DEFAULT VALUES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx): Forces the new row to contain the default values
>   defined for each column.